# How does PowerShell split unquoted command-line arguments?

Tags: powershell

PowerShell does not split command arguments in the same way as cmd.exe or sh. The behaviour I'm stumbling over is that a `.` character sometimes, but not always, starts a new argument.

To illustrate:

```
PS D:\temp> gc .\list-args.py
import sys
print(*sys.argv, sep='\n')

PS D:\temp> py .\list-args.py a.txt .\b -c=d -e=.\f -g.h -.i=j
.\list-args.py
a.txt
.\b
-c=d
-e=
.\f
-g
.h
-.i=j
PS D:\temp>
```

**What rules does Powershell use to separate one command-line argument from the next?**

Where are these documented?

Comment: You could use the *stop parsing symbol* `--%` when you use external commands.

Comment: You may find some more info here: [about Parsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: @Olaf thanks for the hints. `--%` is certainly interesting, but what I could do is not really the point. I can simply wrap my arguments in quotes. about_Parsing looks like it should answer the question, but I don't think it actually does... Neither does [about_Command_Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_command_syntax?view=powershell-7.1) as far as I can tell

Comment: The `.` is most commonly used in powershell to say "execute this".  Either manipulate the data as strings, or as others have suggested tweak the parser.

Comment: I found another document that feels like it should contain the answer: [Appendix C: The PowerShell grammar](https://manning-content.s3.amazonaws.com/download/2/4aee82f-9192-4e50-941f-4bfde960b998/AppCexcerpt.pdf) -- it provides a hint in that the `.` is not allowed in `<ParameterToken>`, but other characters not allowed  in that pattern don't behave the same way so that's also no help

Answer (score 0):

Here's echoargs output (http://ss64.com/ps/EchoArgs.exe).

```
.\echoargs .\list-args.py a.txt .\b -c=d -e=.\f -g.h -.i=j

Arg 0 is <.\list-args.py>
Arg 1 is <a.txt>
Arg 2 is <.\b>
Arg 3 is <-c=d>
Arg 4 is <-e=>
Arg 5 is <.\f>
Arg 6 is <-g>
Arg 7 is <.h>
Arg 8 is <-.i=j>
```

One quoting workaround:

```
.\echoargs .\list-args.py a.txt .\b -c=d -e='.\f' '-g.h' -.i=j

Arg 0 is <.\list-args.py>
Arg 1 is <a.txt>
Arg 2 is <.\b>
Arg 3 is <-c=d>
Arg 4 is <-e=.\f>
Arg 5 is <-g.h>
Arg 6 is <-.i=j>
```

`.` might be used for property references.

```
$a = [pscustomobject]@{name='joe'}
write-output $a.name

joe
```

The command line parses arrays too.

```
$b = 1,2,3
write-output $b[0]

1
```

Comment: I know what the args are, that's what those two lines of Python tell us. What I'm asking is why.

Comment: Like I said, my guess is the dot is being parsed for a property reference.